# How to use merge_as to merge two dataframe on two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, with two index, `name, time`

what i want is to merge them on `name` and `time`.

for example:

```
In [30]: import numpy as np

In [31]: a = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)))

In [32]: b = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(range(25), (5,5)))

In [33]: a['name'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c','d']

In [34]: b['name'] = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c','d']

In [35]: a
Out[35]: 
    0   1   2   3   4 name
0   0   1   2   3   4    a
1   5   6   7   8   9    b
2  10  11  12  13  14    c
3  15  16  17  18  19    c
4  20  21  22  23  24    d

In [36]: b
Out[36]: 
    0   1   2   3   4 name
0   0   1   2   3   4    a
1   5   6   7   8   9    b
2  10  11  12  13  14    b
3  15  16  17  18  19    c
4  20  21  22  23  24    d

In [38]: pd.merge_asof(a, b, on=['name', 4], tolerance=pd.Timedelta('200ms'), direction='nearest', suffixes=['', '_x'])  # here failed
```

for `name`, i need to match exactly. for `time`, i can have a edurance.

i know `merge_as` can merge dataframe on times with a intervals.

but i found it cant be used in two columns.

can you help on this? how to merge them with exactly match on `name` and intervals match on `time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass with by for exact match , and also need convert to datetime

```
a['key'] = pd.to_datetime(a[4])
b['key'] = pd.to_datetime(b[4])
out = pd.merge_asof(a, b, by = ['name'],on=['key'], tolerance=pd.Timedelta('200ms'), direction='nearest', suffixes=['', '_x'])
Out[59]: 
    0   1   2   3   4  ... 0_x 1_x  2_x  3_x  4_x
0   0   1   2   3   4  ...   0   1    2    3    4
1   5   6   7   8   9  ...   5   6    7    8    9
2  10  11  12  13  14  ...  15  16   17   18   19
3  15  16  17  18  19  ...  15  16   17   18   19
4  20  21  22  23  24  ...  20  21   22   23   24
```